Calculation in Prediction for an MA(1)
When we calculate $\theta_{n1}$, why does the summation in $(3.79)$ become zero?
$$\theta_{t, 1} = \theta_{t, t-(t-1)}= \frac{\gamma(1) - \sum_{k=0}^{t-2} \theta_{t-1, t-1-k} \theta_{t, t-k} P_{k+1}^k}{P_{t}^{t-1}}$$


